# Formatting time with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to working with XSLT stylesheets. I've extracted this string from an XML sheet and need to change the time format from 24 hours with seconds (e.g. 13:52:43) to 12 hours with AM or PM (e.g. 1:52 PM).

I'd prefer using `<xsl:choose>` and `<xsl:when>`.

Here is my current progress but it doesn't work since the string can't be compared to an integer.

```
<xsl:variable name="origTime" select="(substring(./string[8],12,8))" />
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$origTime > 13">
      *etc.*
    </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Apparently you are using XSLT 2.0 or higher. Is there a reason why you cannot use the built-in `format-time()` function?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion the OP is using XSLT 2.0+

Comment: Please always say which XSLT version you are using; many problems become much easier with XSLT 2.0+, but a surprising number of people are still using the ancient XSLT 1.0. This makes it very hard to answer questions unless we know.

Comment: @MichaelKay Because they would not get the error they report in XSLT 1.0. Instead, the string would be implicitly converted to a number according to the rules of comparison specified in XPath 1.0: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans

Comment: @michael.hor257k You're reading a lot into the phrasing of the question - you might be right but who knows.

Comment: Well, that's why I asked.